# Using Linq to Entities with OrderByDescending and SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I'm seeing behavior with Linq to Entitites that isn't in line with my understanding of how Linq works.  Please consider the following snippet:

```
MWGRCEntities entities = new MWGRCEntities();

foreach (EDMXModel.Classes.RiskScoreMetric rsm in entities.RiskScoreMetrics.Where(rsmq.StatusCode != (int)KnownCodes.RiskScoreMetricStatusInActive))
{
    //Magic happens here...
    rsm.ImpactOverall = (rsm.ImpactWorkingGroup + rsm.ImpactExecutive) / 2;
    rsm.LikelihoodOverall = (rsm.LikelihoodWorkingGroup + rsm.LikelihoodExecutive) / 2;
}

int rank = 0;
double prevScore = -1;
double score = -2;
foreach (EDMXModel.Classes.RiskScoreMetric rsm in entities.RiskScoreMetrics.Where(rsmq.StatusCode != (int)KnownCodes.RiskScoreMetricStatusInActive).OrderByDescending(rsmq => Math.Round((Math.Round(rsmq.ImpactOverall, 3) + Math.Round(rsmq.LikelihoodOverall, 3)), 3)))
{
    score = Math.Round((Math.Round(rsm.ImpactOverall, 3) + Math.Round(rsm.LikelihoodOverall, 3)), 3);

    if (score != prevScore)
        rank++;

    rsm.Ranking = rank;
    prevScore = score;
}

entities.SaveChanges();
```

I expected the RiskScoreMetric objects would be sorted in the second foreach loop using the ImpactOverall and LikelihoodOverall values set in first foreach loop.  It appears, however, that Linq is sorting in the second foreach loop based on the original ImpactOverall and LikelihoodOverall values (as in, the values in the database not those in memory).  I can readily fix the code simply by adding a second call to entities.SaveChanges() immediately prior to the second foreach loop.

Can anyone tell me if this behavior is expected and if so why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that the `OrderbyDescending` you are using here is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. This extension method and the LINQ expression you are using as parameter of this method - `rsmq => Math.Round(...)` - doesn't get executed on a data structure/collection in memory, but it merely represents an expression tree. What actually happens with that expression tree depends on the data provider (that is referenced inside of queryable object of type `IQueryable<T>`). In case of Entity Framework/LINQ to Entities this provider will translate the expression tree into an SQL string (of a dialect that depends on the details of that provider, for example T-SQL for SQL Server, some other native SQL dialect for Oracle or MySQL, etc.).

The translated SQL gets send to the database server and will be executed in the database engine which doesn't know anything about the change you have made to the already loaded entities in memory.

**All** LINQ to Entities queries are always executed in the database based on the current state and data values in the tables. They never consider if you already have loaded the entities, which values they have and no matter if changed or not. (`DbSet<T>.Find` or `ObjectSet<T>.GetObjectByKey` are the only exceptions that check if the entity with the supplied key is already loaded in memory, but those methods are not LINQ to Entities queries, although they will issue a LINQ to Entities query, namely `SingleOrDefault`, if they couldn't find the entity as already attached to the context.)

As a side note: The need to translate an expression tree into SQL is also the reason why you cannot use arbitrary .NET methods in a LINQ to Entites query because in most cases there is no translation into SQL possible or the LINQ to Entities provider does not know how to translate it. Something like...

```
rsmq => MySpecialRoundMethod(...)
```

...where `MySpecialRoundMethod` is a custom method you have written in C# will work with LINQ to Objects (on an `IEnumerable<T>`) but not with LINQ to Entities (on an `IQueryable<T>`). It happens to be that for `Math.Round(...)` a translation into SQL is implemented, so that you can use it with Entity Framework.

Comment: Awesome response.  Thank you very much.  I had noticed that some methods couldn't be used in these expressions and didn't know why.  I now understand what's going on a lot more.  Does this mean that if I insert an object into a context then try to find it with a select linq query I won't find it because it hasn't been inserted into the database?

Comment: @AEberhard: Yes, exactly. The exception you have seen is probably the infamous "cannot translate into store expression" exception and it's one of most asked questions what that means. I believe what people confuses about this is the term "store expression" which in 99% of all cases just means "SQL". I think they are using the more abstract term because EF doesn't require a translation into SQL. If there were a company with a special DB system and a proprietary query language called "Babble" they could write a LINQ to Entities provider for Babble. The "store expression" would be "Babble" then.